# Write configuration to config.yml

Tags: symfony

I have a service which have definition something like this

```
puff_service:
    driver: mysql
```

I know how to load the configuration but in this case I would like to write this configuration in config.yml automatically when people install the bundle for the first time. Is there anyway to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enhance your bundle with a [bundle extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html#using-the-bundle-extension) in which is possible to specify default values without forcing final user to write them in `config.yml`

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('puff_service');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('driver')
                    ->default('mysql')
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

This way, who include your bundle will have as default driver mysql; if a change is needed, they can specify it directly in `config.yml`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. As I mentioned I know how to load the config (and set the defaults) and I know user can put entry manually in config.yml.  What I want is to add these entry automatically in config.yml when user installs the bundle so that user can see default settings without reading the docs. Just like when you install Symfony you will see few configurations already populated in config.yml.

Comment: @nicholasnet this is done with a .yml.dist file containing all the default values.

Comment: @Veve As far as I know that is for parameters not for config. Also there is no automated way to edit any .dist file that I am aware of.

Comment: @nicholasnet if you take a look to any bundle, you'll see, in README.MD, an entry where contributors explain you what parameter to insert into config file: as fare as I know, there is no automatic way for do this (and, to me, is totally useless: RTFM :P)

Comment: @DonCallisto I use to think it's useless but not so much now. Imagine you install Symfony and manually adding each and every config mentioned in config.yml after installing a framework and tell user RTFM.....not cool right. Now I agree not every bundle needs this feature but it's certainly handy for some. Anyway it is what it is.